# Expected to see "initializer-string for array of chars is too long" warning

Tags: c, gcc

I expected to see  "initializer-string for array of chars is too long" warning for both of the variables in the following program using gcc.

Program:

```
int main()
{
   char str1[4]="1234";
   char str2[3]="1234";

   (void)str1; // Remove unused variable warning.
   (void)str2; // Remove unused variable warning.
   return 0;
}
```

However, I got a warning only for `str2`.

Since

```
char str1[4]="1234";
```

is equivalent to

```
char str1[4]= {'1', '2', '3', '4', '\0'};
```

shouldn't we get the same warning for `str1` also?

Is this a defect in gcc?

Compiler command:

> gcc -Wall -std=c99     soc.c   -o soc

`gcc` version is 4.8.4.

**Update**

Learned just now that

```
char str1[4]="1234";
```

**is not** equivalent to

```
char str1[4]= {'1', '2', '3', '4', '\0'};
```

**Update 2**

```
char str1[4]="1234";
```

is ill-formed in C++11 (Section 8.5.2/2). I didn't think C99 and C++11 would treat them differently.

Comment: See [No compiler error when fixed size char array is initialized without enough room for null terminator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20694796/1708801)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Section 6.7.9 of the C standard reads:

> 14. An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
>       literal or UTF −8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.
>       Successive bytes of the string literal (**including the terminating
>       null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size**)
>       initialize the elements of the array.
>
> ...
>
> 32. EXAMPLE 8
>
>     The declaration
>
>     ```
>     char s[] = "abc", t[3] = "abc";
>     ```
>
>     defines ‘‘plain’’ char array objects s and t whose elements are initialized with character string literals. This declaration is identical to
>
>     ```
>     char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' }, t[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
>     ```

(Emphasis mine).

That is, the terminating null character is not added if it does not fit into the fixed known size array.